# How to change pixel color in OpenglES

Tags: android, opengl-es

want to change the pixel color from camera preview (Live) , is that is possible using OpenGL ES FRAGMENT_SHADER ?

currently i have code to process camera preview ,
one snippets for B/W preview.

```
"#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "    vec4 tc = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "    float color = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
                "    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, color, color, 1.0);\n" +
                "}\n";
```

so is there any way to process single pixels only and change theres color using shader.

i want to change yellow color pixels to green color pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific about your algorithm but what you are saying would be kind of:

```
vec4 tc = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
if(tc.r > .9 && tc.g > .9 && tc.b < .1) { // very yellow color
    gl_FragColor = vec4(.0, 1.0, .0, 1.0);
}
else {
    gl_FragColor = tc;
}
```

You might want a bit smarter algorithm though. Something that would balance the pixels that are more yellow to be more green. This requires a bit of imagination and a lot of playing with different sample, images to see the result. For instance you might try to compute a factor that indicates how yellow the pixel is and then use this factor to mix the original pixel color with green color:

```
     vec4 tc = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
     highp float yellowScale = ((sTexture.r + sTexture.g)*.5) * // intensity factor
                               (1.0-sTexture.b) * // discard blue factor
                               (1.0 - abs(sTexture.r - sTexture.g)); // pure yellow factor
     gl_FragColor = mix(tc, vec4(.0, 1.0, .0, 1.0), yellowScale);
```

This is just something written on the fly, you will need to play around with it a bit.